# Excel table sorting function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I'm working on a music survey thing for a project in school. This is a screenshot of some of the results (the responses are not in english, sorry about that):

[image]

The cells to the right is the musical time period(s) the respondents prefer. Currently, I have a table that sorts how many times any gender has picked the specific time period. For instance, 20 people picked the 80's as one of their preffered time periods:

[image]

Below is the function I used.

```
=COUNTIF(CellStart:CellEnd;"*80'erne*")
```

Is it possible to also sort by gender based on the information I have? (basically fill out the "men" and "women" rows)

Comment: See [Comment link](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the formula to a `COUNTIFS`.

Do the same thing you do for a `countif`, except add a second criteria range and set the criteria as "Male" or "Female" so you can then look at the time period and the sex of the respondent.

```
=COUNTIFS(CellStart:CellEnd,"*80'erne*",CellStart:CellEnd,"Enter Sex Here")
```